# Use values from XML in javascript foreach

Tags: javascript, xml, telerik

I am writing a dropdown list in the Kendo Editor custom tools that needs to show smart tag values to be placed into the textarea.  My javascript code looks like this:

```
$("#editor").kendoEditor({
            resizable: {
                content: true,
                toolbar: true
            },
            tools: [
                {
                    name: "insertHtml",
                    items: [
                        { text: "TEXT", value: "VALUE" },
                        { text: "TEXT", value: "VALUE" }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            messages: {
                insertHtml: "Placeholders"
            }
        });
```

I have an XML file with all the values that need to be populated.

```
<SMARTTAGS>
<TAG>
<TEXT>Login Link</TEXT>
<VALUE>[FASTSIGNLINK]</VALUE>
</TAG>
<TAG>
<TEXT>Enrollment Registration Link</TEXT>
<VALUE>[SIGNLINK]</VALUE>
</TAG>
<TAG>
<TEXT>Onboarding Login Link</TEXT>
<VALUE>[OBLINK]</VALUE>
</TAG>
```

How can i get these values into my javascript items (in the TEXT and VALUE areas) so that all i have to do is update the xml file if i want to add / remove text/values?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try something like that.

```
tags = document.getElementsByTagName('SMARTTAGS')[0].getElementsByTagName('TAG');
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0,c=tags.length; i<c; i++) {
    arr.push({
        text: tags[i].getElementsByTagName("TEXT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        value: tags[i].getElementsByTagName("VALUE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    });
}
```

I dont know if it is the best way to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the xml from somewhere else, you can just use [parseXML](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/):

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( "<SMARTTAGS><TAG><TEXT>Login Link</TEXT><VALUE>[FASTSIGNLINK]</VALUE></TAG><TAG><TEXT>Enrollment Registration Link</TEXT><VALUE>[SIGNLINK]</VALUE></TAG><TAG><TEXT>Onboarding Login Link</TEXT><VALUE>[OBLINK]</VALUE></TAG></SMARTTAGS>" );
var xml = $( xmlDoc );
var tags = xml.find("TAG");
var items = [];
for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++){
    var tag = $(tags[i]);
    items.push({
        text: tag.find("TEXT")[0].innerHTML, value: tag.find("VALUE")[0].innerHTML
    })
}
```